# How can i test kivy apps?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to test my kivy app for android, someone know how can i do it ? 
i tried the android studio emulator, but it's too heavy for my computer.

I need to know how widgets will behave on the phone screen, because the computer is very different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the emulator from within Android Studio? If so, to save memory you can run it from the command line instead, without having Android Studio running at the same time. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline You can also save memory by editing the emulator default settings to disable features you're not using, and reduce the amount of memory used for some features. You might also want to try the Genymotion Android Emulator.

Comment: thank you, it worked. 
u know if i need to compile my App.py to apk before test in android emulator or can i test directly? i dont see any option to add apk or anything

Comment: Great! Personally so far I've only used Kivy on the Raspberry Pi and Windows (and have written Android apps in Java), but you can read instructions in the "Installing an app" section of the page linked to in my answer above.